# Move a rectangle which has gradient fill

Tags: java, graphics, awt, gradient, graphics2d

When I use the coordinates of (0,0) "Rectangle(0,0,100,100)" for the rectangle I get gradient. When I use:

```
GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, c1, 0, 100, c2);
Rectangle reckt = new Rectangle(0,100,100,200);
```

the gradient disappears. What am I doing wrong?

```
 public void draw( Graphics g ) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    c1 = new Color(0, 0, 255);
    c2 = new Color(0, 255, 255);
    GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, c1, 0, 100, c2);

    g2d.setPaint(gp);
    Rectangle reckt = new Rectangle(0,0,100,100);
    g2d.fill(reckt);

}
```

Comment: Use a AffineTransform and translate the position, then simply draw/paint at 0x0. Just don't forget to reset it after your done

Answer (score 1):

The first two parameters define the x/y point at which the gradient starts and the fourth and fifth define the height and width. So basically, you're drawing your rectangle beyond the the gradient fill

You have two options, either change the x/y position if the `GradientFill` or use a `AffineTransform` and `translate` the `Graphics` context to where you want to paint and simply always paint at 0x0 for both

A `AffineTransform` allows you to translate (among other things) the `Graphics` top/left position, for example...

[image: Translated]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestTranslate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTranslate();
    }

    public TestTranslate() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Color c1 = new Color(0, 0, 255);
            Color c2 = new Color(0, 255, 255);
            GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, c1, 0, 100, c2);
            for (int offset = 0; offset < getWidth(); offset += 50) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                g2d.setPaint(gp);
                g2d.setTransform(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(offset, offset));
                g2d.fill(new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100));
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you help me with the AffineTransform?

Comment: I used:

       'AffineTransform move = new AffineTransform();
       move.translate(200, 200);
    g2d1.setTransform(move);'